# Probablity of picking up 3 vowels from the word "MATHEMATICS"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Each of the letters in the word "MATHEMATICS" is on a letter tile in a
>   bag. Foool picks three without replacement. what is the probability
>   that he will get all vowels?

My approach,

The number of ways to the letters of the words "MATHEMATICS" can be arranged 3 at a time is coefficient of $x^3 $ $$ 3! \times  (1+x)^5 \times \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^3$$ which is $399$

The number of arrangements of 2A's, 1I and 1E taken 3 at at a time is coefficient of $x^3$ in  $$ 3! \times  (1+x)^2 \times  \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$ which is $12$.

Then the required probability is given by $\frac {12}{399} $ but apparently this is not the right answer. What exactly I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How many ways are there to pick 3 letters? How many ways are there to pick 3 vowels? By my count, the right answer should be $$\binom{4}{3}/\binom{11}{3}=\frac{4}{165}.$$

Comment: Thanks Arturo, I just over-complicated a simple problem :(

Comment: You have *four* items: four physical tiles; they are different objects, because they are *different tiles*. Just because two of them have the same letter written on them does not make them the same tile!

Comment: Thanks again Arturo, I was all messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're missing, because I don't know why you're taking the approach you take. The answer is $(4/11)(3/10)(2/9)$.

Comment: But there is repetition of letters, so why would this work?

Comment: What difference does repetition make? If it were MATHEMOTICS, how would it be different?

Comment: Why do repetitions matter? You have one tile for each letter, so you have 11 tiles. Of these 11 tiles, 4 tiles contain vowels. If you grab 3 tiles, what are the odds that all 3 tiles are vowels? Where the letters come from, or what the letters are, is irrelevant; the problem works exactly the same way if four tiles have an A in them and seven tiles have a B; or if four tiles are A, E, I, O, and the other seven are B, C, D, F, G, H, J. You are not being asked for the possible number of 3-letter sequences that can be made from the letters in "MATHEMATICS" (where repetitions would matter).

Comment: Foool: You are confusing this question with the question "What are the different possibilities of picking three vowels?". In this case the repetitions would matter.

Answer (score -1):

We obtained  vowels in a word =5 (a ,e i,  o ,u ) 
    And numbers of word = 11

A/Q        the probability of picking up a vowel = 5/ 11  ans